# Ubiquity Won't Start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, ubiquity

I am trying to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. My computer has had problems with Ubiquity before (GRUB wouldn't install) but this time Ubiquity won't even start. When I ran it from the Terminal it didn't give any error messages but nothing showed up. I tried selecting the "Install Ubuntu" option at boot and it still didn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

Edit: It isn't a duplicate because that tells how to install it with Ubiquity. With this, I can't run Ubiquity.
Edit2: I just tried 16.04 and it worked!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: @user535733 I reinstalled it with a different ISO and it still didn't work. Also, I've used the drive before.